# Get start and end time of current playing song

Tags: shoutcast, internet-radio

I am trying to implement a radio stream switcher in android. What I would like to do, in the desired order, is this:

1. Start streaming a radio station
2. Get the endTime of the current playing song from that station
3. At endTime - Delta, I want to scan a list of stations and I want to get back a list of stations that have a new song starting in the interval [endTime, endTime + Delta']
4. Switch to a stream from the result set in [3] and then repeat

So, I can stream a radio station (no problem). I can get a notification when the song changes (using streamscraper to fetch metadata and generate a notification when the metadata changes). However, what I have not been able to find out is whether it is possible to do the following:

1. Get the endTime of the current playing song
2. Scan a list of stations, and get songs that have started around the same time (so get startTime of songs) or songs that might be starting soon (if endTime of current song in those streams is near or if I can actually get the stream programme in advance).

If anyone could tell me whether this is possible, I would be obliged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible.  You cannot know the end time of what is playing until it stops playing.  The data just isn't there, and isn't even applicable to all streams.  (Think of live programs, DJ-mixed shows, cross-fading start/end points, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for this. I now have another reason to further explain my inability of implementing this feature. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something similar to what you are referring to with SHOUTcast. I am not sure how the log files for Icecast are formatted but I was able to use PHP to basically watch the logs for the "Song Change" event.

Once you are able to do so, you can execute code as needed. If you want to know the length of the title playing, you can start a timer when the song is updated and stop it once the song has changed again.

It's a bit tricky but it does work.. www.soundcheck.xyz - Automatically posts current playing song to Twitter in real time.

Answer (score -1):

A stream consists of a seamless stream of mp3´s
thats what a stream does...it stiches separate mp3´s to one large stream.

But theres track ID-tags in the stream...not shure if you can find end and start from them
or if these start exactly at the track-start or other fixed positions.

Most stations dont send ahead info about the next track
simply cause they dont know, most use auto-dj playlists where the server has to decide
in the small break between old and new track what that new track will be
ie: it dont decide on that while the old track is playing.

Some stations do send info (PHP to their webpages) what the next track will be
but most dont...and if they do that info is ceretainly not in the stream itself.

Maybe a trick could be to add a delay for your listener
ie: what the listener is hearing currently
is old (up to a few minutes or 1 complete track)

Not shure how to create such delay...maybe you need to record (buffer) it
and play it back with a delay (in your app or via some additional server)

Your (not delayed) application will (hopefully) notice when the current song has ended
since a new one has started with a new ID2/3 tag...it will switch your listener to a new stream    when his current but delayed song has ended.

Said different ...below the surface your application is looking ahead (relative to the listener)

You need to study the Shoutcast and ID-tag protocols.
Additional silence-detection might help also (not foolproof).

May not always work..some stations dont send ID tags
others crossfade their tracks (no silence)...exactly to avoid these tricks.

Or something like that...good luck i cant code anything..its just theory
i suspect some shoutcast rippers to use this trick...i suppose they use this
to scan multitple streams (in parallel) for certain preset artists-tracks.
Maybe you can get some ideas by reverse-engineering those rippers. 
Since i have a radio myself i´m not a fan of these tricks since they steal from me
while i pay for the rights....to many rippers will kill online radio.

In the end i dont see your idea (if i understand its purpose well) as usefull anyway
switching from one to another stream every next track dont seem like a enjoying experience.
Good radiostations will have a carefully made (ordered) playlist
if you mess that up your listener will get to much mood/style variations in a to short time.

The only usefull purpose for this is probably to build a automated ripper
that can distract preset tracks/artist from a multitude of in parralel observed streams
and record them when a wanted track is played...for many online stations those rippers are a big problem already, 10´s more of those rippers and online radio is dead...as result good quality and independent music wont be available anymore...and we will be stuck with only Youtube and other
money infested conglomerates..i´m not looking forward to that....curious if you have an other usefull
purpose.

Comment: Continuous MP3 streams over HTTP do not contain ID3 tags.  If they did, the audio would be corrupt.  The auto-DJ applications and scripts do not blindly concatenate MP3 files together... they have to stitch the streams together.  Some even re-encode the audio (as this is much easier than dealing with bit reservoir issues).

Comment: @Brad: Mp3´s do not contain iD3 tags...if they did the audio would be corrupt ... ofcourse that is not true ... they DO CONTAIN iD3 tags...just as mp3 streams also DO CONTAIN iD3 tags.

Comment: You are mis-quoting me.  I said, "Continuous MP3 streams over HTTP do not contain ID3 tags."  I assure you that this is true.  If you think otherwise, I suggest providing proof.  To clarify what I am referring to, I am not talking about simply loading an MP3 file over HTTP.  I am talking about radio-like streams.

Comment: yes Brad ...i have a shoutcast radiostream myself in MP3 format which is by far the most used ..and it contains iD3 tags and other stuff/info ...if we speak about radiostreams we usually refere to this kind of streams. here´s a 1 on 1 copy: "The SHOUTcast software uses a client–server model, with each component communicating via a network protocol that intermingles audio or video data with metadata such as song titles and the station name. It uses HTTP as a transport protocol." from this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHOUTcast   does that pass your criteria for proof ?

Comment: SHOUTcast/Icecast streams are exactly what I am talking about, and I assure you they do not contain ID3 tags.  Look at any packet trace for such a stream, and you will not find ID3 tags.  The only metadata a SHOUTcast/Icecast stream can contain is the SHOUTcast metadata itself, inserted periodically into the stream.  Anything else is sent straight to the MPEG decoder, which does not understand ID3.

Comment: Heres how i (have to) add artist-track info to my (mp3) shoutcast-stream in order for them to show up in any player that can display it: ... before i upload my mp3´s i need to add the standard iD3 tags to them ..if i dont they dont show up at the player..ie: only way that you could be correct is when before the mp3s are stiched to a stream something distracts the iD3´s from the MP3´s and adds them to the stream in the lets call it "overhead part" of the stream which is not the mp3-part in the stream but separate info ..is that what you are saying ?

Comment: Yes! Your media fiels need their ID3 tags so that the encoder (autostreamer, MP3 player, whatever) knows what metadata to send to the SHOUTcast server.  They are sent to SHOUTcast out-of-band from the regular audio stream data.  At this point, they have nothing to do with ID3.  The SHOUTcast server then creates a stream with SHOUTcast-format metadata interleaved with the stream data.  It is in the format of `StreamTitle='Artist - Title';StreamURL=;`.  The client reading the stream separates the audio stream data from the metadata, sending the audio stream to the codec.

Comment: that means ... a player..for example winamp handles a shoutcast-mp3-stream different then a normal mp3 ?

Comment: Exactly!  The same MPEG codec is used, but handling of metadata is completely different.  The key is whether or not `Icy-MetaInt` is in the response header from the server.  See also:  http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html

Comment: Wondering why the id3 data needs to be separated from the mp3 data ...why dont they just leave it in ?

Comment: Think about this from how it works for typical MP3 files.  The MP3 decoder knows nothing about ID3 tags.  It doesn't get the whole file.  It is up to the player to split out the metadata from the stream.  Now for streaming media, how would the player know when the next ID3 tag comes up?  How would it know the difference between the ID3 tag and the stream data?  The only way the player knows for files is because of the location the ID3 tag is in the file.  For streams, it could be anywhere.  Therefore, a new system was devised.

Comment: "How would it know the difference" ...it could look (continiously) for an iD3-tag which would look different from stream-data, anyway they did it different so we have to live with it.

Comment: You would honestly prefer the overhead of a parser looking for `TAG` before sending bytes off to the codec?  What for, when you could insert metadata at a fixed interval?

Comment: Not shure ... but obviously it is how it is ..tnx !