# How can I show the progress of a song on a SHOUTcast stream?

Tags: jplayer, shoutcast

To play a SHOUTcast stream on my website I am using [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) and in particular the [CirclePlayer](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-05/). When playing normal MP3 files it shows the progress of a track: there is a green progress bar that shows how much of the current track has played, but with a SHOUTcast stream this does not work.

I have been doing some research and it seems impossible to make it work for streams:

- [The public metadata on `/stats?sid=1` doesn't give the length of the current track](http://wiki.winamp.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_DNAS_Server_2_XML_Reponses#General_Server_Summary)
- It is possible to get the length of a song through the [stream metadata](http://wiki.winamp.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_DNAS_Server_2_XML_Reponses#Stream_Metadata), but then you still don't know how long the song has been playing. [That info doesn't seem available](http://wiki.winamp.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_XML_Metadata_Specification).

Am I correct that it is impossible (or at least very difficult and inaccurate) to show the progress of the current track in a SHOUTcast stream? If not, how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10050260/362536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [it cannot be done](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=370439):

> SHOUTcast streams were never intended to indicate per-song position as
>   it can be done but requires protocol changes and everything from the
>   source software to the client player to cope with and support it.